# Are the Apple text-to-speech voices copyrighted?

Tags: audio, text-to-speech, copyright

I want to use an excerpt of an OS X text-to-speech voice in a song that I am recording. Is there any kind of copyright restriction for recordings of the computer voice I should know about, or are they totally free for anyone to use for any purpose?

Comment: Apparently not. Does anyone have a suggestion for some TTS software that *is* free for commercial use?

Comment: Let's leave this question as is and just ask that separate question linking back here as one option you have ruled out...

Comment: Sure, sounds good.

Comment: If you're looking for online voice generator, check out http://www.ivona.com/en/recordings/ or https://acapela-box.com/AcaBox/index.php. You only pay for generating speech from your text, and you can then use it for any purpose you want.

Comment: $ say -v Fred "Fitter, happier, more productive"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are not free to use them for any purpose, only for personal, non-commercial use while running Apple software. Read [Mac OS X Lion Software License Agreement](http://www.apple.com/legal/sla/) for full details (section G, it is rather short and clear):

> *Voices* Subject to the terms and conditions of this License, you may use the system voices included in the Apple Software (“System Voices”) (i) while running the Apple Software and (ii) to create your own original content and projects for your personal, non-commercial use. No other use of the System Voices is permitted by this License, including but not limited to the use, reproduction, display, performance, recording, publishing or redistribution of any of the System Voices in a profit, non-profit, public sharing or commercial context.