# Is there any real-time text-to-speech software?

Tags: software-recommendation, text-to-speech

I type really fast. Almost as fast as I speak. Is there any software that synthesizes text in real-time, as I type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dragon Naturally Speaking v6](http://www.nuance.com/for-individuals/by-product/dragon-for-mac/software/) may be an option. Trial available [here](http://www.nuance.com/dragon/dragon-trials/). Have used with school and it performed well in loud environments as well as those that are quiet. Doesn't need an internet connection after downloaded, so is a very good idea. Also, the macOS [built in dictation software](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT202584) may be downloaded for free, but is not as reliable.

For more, see [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43307/whats-a-free-or-cheap-text-to-speech-program-that-is-available-for-commercial-u?rq=1), which says

> [eSpeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/download.html) is a brilliant opensource text to speech project. It's the default TTS software on many Linux distributations, but there's a Mac version available and it works great. There is also a project based on eSpeak called [Mbrola](http://tcts.fpms.ac.be/synthesis/) which adds "singing" functionality.